# In a dockerfile, can we have multiple RUN commands into one RUN command?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-run

I understand that each RUN command creates a layer. Suppose I have the following RUN commands:

```
RUN python -m pip install --upgrade pip
RUN python -m pip install --upgrade setuptools
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
```

I wish to run all the command in one run command. Is the below OK to use?

```
RUN python -m pip install --upgrade pip; python -m pip install --upgrade setuptools; pip install -r requirements.txt
```

If I use the following, then it gives me an error "The token '&&' is not a valid statement separator in this version.":

```
RUN python -m pip install --upgrade pip && python -m pip install --upgrade setuptools && pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Comment: replace ```;``` with ```&&```

Comment: It says: The token '&&' is not a valid statement separator in this version.

Comment: Essentially every Dockerfile does exactly what you show.  Do you have a `SHELL` declaration earlier in the file that's changing the default behavior?  Or are you using some unusual base image?

Answer (score 10):

Yes you can and its a good practice

Instead of doing this

```
RUN python -m pip install --upgrade pip
RUN python -m pip install --upgrade setuptools
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Try this

```
RUN python -m pip install --upgrade pip &&\
    python -m pip install --upgrade setuptools &&\
    pip install -r requirements.txt
```

**Advantages with that approach**

Each instruction in the Dockerfile adds an extra layer to the docker image 
The number of instructions and layers should be kept to a minimum as it ultimately affects the build performance and time

Comment: It gives an error: The token '&&' is not a valid statement separator in this version.

Comment: Is there a way to have comments for each line with this approach?

Comment: About build performance: If you have multiple layers, and you only change the top layer, then the lower layers won't be rebuilt. So subsequent rebuilds can actually be faster if you have multiple layers, if the lower layers are cached.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is ok to combine RUN commands and it will reduce the number of layers in the docker image too!

`RUN python -m pip install --upgrade pip && python -m pip install --upgrade setuptools && pip install -r requirements.txt`

Should do!

UPDATE: Please try this command.

```py
RUN python -m pip install --upgrade pip && python -m pip install --upgrade setuptools && pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Comment: It says: The token '&&' is not a valid statement separator in this version.

Comment: Can you please share the Dockerfile for this?

Comment: Sorry, my bad, the commands should be called by Python. Can you please see the update?

Comment: Same error: The token '&&' is not a valid statement separator in this version.

Answer (score 0):

It is encouraged to combine multiple RUN statements, as it reduces the number of layers created

See: https://github.com/mysql/mysql-docker/blob/mysql-server/5.7/Dockerfile